# Launch iOS App on long press of home button / volume button(s)

Tags: ios

If the above scenario is possible then immediately I need to Send SMS/invoke service call after my app is launched.

Answer (score 1):

The above scenario is not possible. It is an OS level functionality. But you can do what ever you want when your app is launched either in the [application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:) method in your AppDelegate or the viewDidLoad method of your rootViewController.